# Not able to get the number of correct answers calculated for a Javascript Simple Quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a sample Quiz where I need to calculate the number of correct answers which I have stored in Score variable.
But facing issues. Any help will highly be appreciated

Below is the code

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const start = document.querySelector('#start');
  start.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('#quizBlock').style.display = 'block';
    start.style.display = 'none';
  });
  // quizArray QUESTIONS & ANSWERS
  // q = QUESTION, o = OPTIONS, a = CORRECT ANSWER
  // Basic ideas from https://code-boxx.com/simple-javascript-quiz/
  const quizArray = [{
      q: 'Which one of the following is the capital of USA?',
      o: ['New York', 'Washington DC', 'California', 'Las Vegas'],
      a: 1, // array index 1 - so Earth is the correct answer here
    },
    {
      q: 'Which is the highest mountain on Earth?',
      o: ['K2', 'Annapurna', 'Makalu', 'Everest'],
      a: 3,
    },
    {
      q: 'What is the capital of Sweden',
      o: ['Spain', 'Stockholm', 'Portugal', 'Hawai'],
      a: 1,
    },
    {
      q: 'What is Shawarma',
      o: ['Drink', 'Food', 'Animal', 'Place'],
      a: 1,
    },
  ];


  // function to Display the quiz questions and answers from the object
  const displayQuiz = () => {
    const quizWrap = document.querySelector('#quizWrap');
    let quizDisplay = '';
    quizArray.map((quizItem, index) => {
      quizDisplay += `<ul class="list-group">
                     Q - ${quizItem.q}
                      <li class="list-group-item mt-2" id="li_${index}_0"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_0"> ${quizItem.o[0]}</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item" id="li_${index}_1"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_1"> ${quizItem.o[1]}</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"  id="li_${index}_2"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_2"> ${quizItem.o[2]}</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"  id="li_${index}_3"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_3"> ${quizItem.o[3]}</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div>&nbsp;</div>`;
      quizWrap.innerHTML = quizDisplay;

    });
  };

  //Event listener for the submit button
  const btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const totalScore = calculateScore(this);
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    console.log('Total Score' + totalScore);
  });

  // Calculate the score
  const calculateScore = () => {
    let score = 0;

    quizArray.map((quizItem, index) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //highlight the li if it is the correct answer
        let li = `li_${index}_${i}`;
        let r = `radio_${index}_${i}`;
        liElement = document.querySelector('#' + li);
        radioElement = document.querySelector('#' + r);
        if (i == 0 && r == 1)
          score = score++;
        if (i == 1 && r == 3)
          score = score++;
        if (i == 2 && r == 1)
          score = score++;
        if (i == 3 && r == 1)
          score = score++;
        console.log('Score In Loop ', score);

        if (quizItem.a == i) {
          //change background color of li element here

        }

        if (radioElement.checked) {
          // code for task 1 goes here
        }
      }
    });
  };

  // call the displayQuiz function
  displayQuiz();
  console.log("Score=" + score);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container m-5" id="start">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Test your knowledge</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick description about the quiz .</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary">Start</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- (B) QUIZ CONTAINER -->
  <div class="container" id="quizBlock" style="display: none">
    <div class="mb-5">
      <h2>Test your knowledge</h2>
      - Time remaining <span id="time">01:00</span>
    </div>
    <div id="quizWrap"></div>

    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">
          Submit Quiz
        </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnReset">
          Reset Quiz
        </button>
      <span id="score"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I also need to highlight the correct answer with a different colour.
I am very new to Javascript so help will highly be appreciated

Comment: Aside: `quizWrap.innerHTML = quizDisplay;` should not be inside the `map()`. Also, `map()` should be `forEach()`, since you're not using the resulting array.

Comment: `score = score++;` should just be `score++;`

Comment: `calculateScore()` need to end with `return score;`

Comment: It would be wonderful if you could provide the code snippet

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. But I am still unable to understand. If you could please provide me the code snippet, that would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't hard-code the checks for correct answers in the loop. When the radio button is checked, test if `i` matches `quizItem.a`. If it does, increment the score. At the same time you can highlight the selected answer with different colors depending on whether it's correct or not.

If it's not checked and is the correct answer, you can then highlight it with a third color.

The syntax for incrementing a variable is either `score = score + 1` or `score++`. Don't combine them, it doesn't work.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const start = document.querySelector('#start');
  start.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('#quizBlock').style.display = 'block';
    start.style.display = 'none';
  });
  // quizArray QUESTIONS & ANSWERS
  // q = QUESTION, o = OPTIONS, a = CORRECT ANSWER
  // Basic ideas from https://code-boxx.com/simple-javascript-quiz/
  const quizArray = [{
      q: 'Which one of the following is the capital of USA?',
      o: ['New York', 'Washington DC', 'California', 'Las Vegas'],
      a: 1, // array index 1 - so Earth is the correct answer here
    },
    {
      q: 'Which is the highest mountain on Earth?',
      o: ['K2', 'Annapurna', 'Makalu', 'Everest'],
      a: 3,
    },
    {
      q: 'What is the capital of Sweden',
      o: ['Spain', 'Stockholm', 'Portugal', 'Hawai'],
      a: 1,
    },
    {
      q: 'What is Shawarma',
      o: ['Drink', 'Food', 'Animal', 'Place'],
      a: 1,
    },
  ];


  // function to Display the quiz questions and answers from the object
  const displayQuiz = () => {
    const quizWrap = document.querySelector('#quizWrap');
    let quizDisplay = '';
    quizArray.map((quizItem, index) => {
      quizDisplay += `<ul class="list-group">
                     Q - ${quizItem.q}
                      <li class="list-group-item mt-2" id="li_${index}_0"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_0"> ${quizItem.o[0]}</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item" id="li_${index}_1"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_1"> ${quizItem.o[1]}</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"  id="li_${index}_2"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_2"> ${quizItem.o[2]}</li>
                      <li class="list-group-item"  id="li_${index}_3"><input type="radio" name="radio${index}" id="radio_${index}_3"> ${quizItem.o[3]}</li>
                      </ul>
                      <div>&nbsp;</div>`;
      quizWrap.innerHTML = quizDisplay;

    });
  };

  //Event listener for the submit button
  const btn = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const totalScore = calculateScore(this);
    console.log('Button Clicked');
    console.log('Total Score = ' + totalScore);
  });

  // Calculate the score
  const calculateScore = () => {
    let score = 0;

    quizArray.map((quizItem, index) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //highlight the li if it is the correct answer
        let li = `li_${index}_${i}`;
        let r = `radio_${index}_${i}`;
        liElement = document.querySelector('#' + li);
        radioElement = document.querySelector('#' + r);
        if (radioElement.checked) {
          if (quizItem.a == i) {
            score++;
            liElement.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          } else {
            liElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          }
        } else if (quizItem.a == i) {
          liElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        }

        console.log('Score In Loop ', score);
      }
    });
    return score;
  };

  // call the displayQuiz function
  displayQuiz();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container m-5" id="start">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Test your knowledge</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick description about the quiz .</p>
        <a class="btn btn-primary">Start</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- (B) QUIZ CONTAINER -->
  <div class="container" id="quizBlock" style="display: none">
    <div class="mb-5">
      <h2>Test your knowledge</h2>
      - Time remaining <span id="time">01:00</span>
    </div>
    <div id="quizWrap"></div>

    <div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">
          Submit Quiz
        </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnReset">
          Reset Quiz
        </button>
      <span id="score"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```